# Can i restore a back up of the user folder to a fresh install without issues?

Tags: backup, time-machine, imac, high-sierra, restore

Can i restore a back up of the user folder to a fresh install without issues?
I created the back up with the disk utility tool

I am fresh installing an iMac late 2015 because it's very slow.
I have backed up the /users/ folder and the /library/ folder.

I have a second question:
Is this a good way to handle this? Or is there any better way?
Would i be able to restore the users folder with time machine without bringing other applications etc?

Comment: So glad you ask about a backup Before starting ! So many don’t...

Comment: @SolarMike Yup! And then they ask "How can I recover my precious data from my hard drive?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you make a backup using Disk Utility? Did you mean you cloned your startup drive? If so, you did not just make a backup of your user folder you made a backup of your **entire** startup disk.

But to answer your original question...

The best way to do what your trying to do is to

1. **Make a [Time Machine Backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201250#backup)**
2. [Erase and Reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph25649?locale=en_US)
3. Use [migration assistant to restore from a Time Machine backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204350) where you can select what content (Your user folder) you would like to transfer
   [image]

**Note:** Usually I would quote all this stuff but this is pretty standard information so I opted to just link it.

Comment: This may be late but do you perhaps know which files i should skip transferring to make the iMac run smoother?

Comment: @DvdB Well I wouldn’t do this process to begin with. It’s not going to really speed up your machine. I do have a couple suggestions that I can give you if your would like.

Comment: Yes please i would love that

Comment: @DvdB [Lets continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79266/room-with-jbis-and-d-vdb)